# Select email from a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I open Outlook and reference a folder. How do I get a dialogue to manually select the email items in the folder?

```
Dim oOlApp As Object, objNmSpc As Object, ofldr As Object

On Error Resume Next

Set oOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

Set objNmSpc = oOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set ofldr = objNmSpc.PickFolder

If Not ofldr Is Nothing Then MsgBox ofldr
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each item in the selected folder as follows...

```
Dim oItem As Object
For Each oItem In ofldr.Items
    Debug.Print oItem.SenderName, oItem.Subject, oItem.ReceivedTime
Next oItem
```

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to see any item in dialogue to select outlook email. It shows only folder

Comment: You can use `ofldr.display` to display the items in a new Explorer object.